# vars.get('var_name') in groovy outputs wrong value in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, groovy

I've defined a variable in JMeter.

[image]

But when I try to access the variable from `Groovy` script it gives `53` instead of `5`, if I put `10` it throws an exception

> javax.script.ScriptException:
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot
> cast object '10' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'int'

Here is my JSR223 Sampler script

```python
int user_number = vars.get("USER_COUNT")
log.info('Total use is '+user_number)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `vars.get("USER_COUNT")` returns a `String` you cannot store that into a `int` variable that's the reason exception is thrown

You should convert the string to int using below way

```java
int user_number = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("USER_COUNT"))
log.info('Total use is '+user_number)
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) and [vars.get()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get-java.lang.String-) function gives you a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

So the options are in:

1. Use the string as it is:

   ```
   String user_number = vars.get("USER_COUNT")
   ```
2. Or convert it to an [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html):

   ```
   int user_number = vars.get("USER_COUNT") as int
   ```